# Specify Python version in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am attempting to create a virtual environment that uses Python 2.7.11 (rather than Ubuntu's 2.7.6). I can successfully create the virtual environment using the following code:

```
virtualenv -p /home/stmist/opt/Python-2.7.11/bin/python2.7 ~/test
```

However, running the following code:

```
source ~/test/bin/activate
python -V
```

indicates that the virtual environment is running 2.7.6. Any suggestions?

Update:

When inside the virtual environment, "pip" modifies packages for 2.7.11, not 2.7.6. I can run Python 2.7.11 using /home/stmist/opt/Python-2.7.11/bin/python2.7. So, the virtual environment is usable, but not ideal.

Comment: It's not especially helpful, but: you haven't done anything obviously wrong, so it's hard to see where the issue could be.

Comment: Maybe, what is in `/home/stmist/opt/Python-2.7.11/bin/` isn't actually Python  2.7.11. What does `/home/stmist/opt/Python-2.7.11/bin/python2.7 -V` say?

Comment: /home/stmist/opt/Python-2.7.11/bin/python2.7 -V returns 
Python 2.7.11

Comment: Let’s try a bit different: what does `~/test/bin/python -V` return?

Comment: ~/test/bin/python -V  returns Python 2.7.11.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting my computer, the virtual environment is now using Python 2.7.11. I don't know whether this is due to the restart, or something else along the way. Thanks to everyone for your help.